# Owner PhotoUrl VisualForce

Tags: visualforce, polymorphism

Is it possible to display the `FullPhotoUrl` or `SmallPhotoUrl` of a `User` owner with `Visualforce` only? I know how I would implement with an extension but I would like to avoid writing one if possible. I've tried the following:

```
<apex:page standardController="Case">
    <apex:variable var="isUser" value="{!Case.Owner.Type == 'User'}" />
    <apex:image value="{!IF(isUser, Case.Owner['SmallPhotoUrl'], ''}" />
</apex:page>
```

The above page will compile but the page gives me an error:

> *Content cannot be displayed: Invalid field*

Comment: Name pointing fields only offer access to a small subset of all available fields. I'm not at all surprised this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Impossible with pure VisualForce. The extension is not particularly difficult to write, however.

```
public with sharing class CaseOwnerExtension
{
    public String ownerHref { get; private set; }
    public String photoUrl { get; private set; }
    public CaseOwnerExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
    {
        Case record = (Case)controller.getRecord();

        if (record.OwnerId.getSObjectType() == User.sObjectType)
        {
            User owner = [SELECT Name, SmallPhotoUrl FROM User WHERE Id = :record.OwnerId];
            photoUrl = owner.SmallPhotoUrl;
            ownerHref = new ApexPages.StandardController(owner).view().getUrl();
        }
        else
        {
            Group owner = [SELECT Name FROM Group WHERE Id = :record.OwnerId];
            ownerHref = new ApexPages.StandardController(owner).view().getUrl();
        }
    }
}
```